# Excel 365 | Nested IFs on cells with formulas

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

I'm applying a nested if statement taking as reference cells with formulas and it's not returning the expected outcome.

Changing cell's content to integer values, the statement works.

Anyone can give me an hand here?
TIA

[my_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fu6w.png)

Comment: As indicated by Gary's Student: what's the sense of the plus in front of the `Right()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
=+RIGHTC2;2)
```

with:

```
=--RIGHT(C2;2)
```

and the others as well!

Comment: That's a neat trick to force the conversion of a string into a number :-)

Comment: Yeah. My problem was exactly finding a way to convert the string to a number automatically. Thank you both Gary and Dominique. Super appreciated your fast help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem can be seen in your Excel screenshot, just by looking at the place where your `AK` values are located: located at the right of the cells means that the values are numbers, but located at the left means that they are strings.

So, the first values you have (18, 18, 08, 12, ...) are not numbers, but strings (pieces of text), which mean in fact ('18', '18', '08', '12', ...), and then you are checking if a piece of text is larger of small than a number.

First you need to convert those pieces of text to an actual number, which you can do using the Excel function `NumberValue()`, and that result can be used inside an IF-formula.